# Make a loop go back to the begining of a list

Tags: python, loops, cross-reference

I’m making a cross reference program in Python. I have a list of 600 data points, and another of 148 data points. I want to cross reference the two to find similar points within a specific range. I know I have to loop through one list, than find where this range is met, however a loop will stop when it is finished with the list. So how do I make it go back to the top of the list once it has reached the end?

```
for idx in hectora:
    matches = np.where(abs(hectora[idx] - ra) < .01)

print idx
```

`hectora` is the list with 600 points; `ra` is the list with 148 points. I want to be able to loop through either one.

Comment: please show us the code you are using

Answer (score 0):

Using the `for` statement on a list will start from the beginning of the list each time you start the loop.

Hence, every

```
for item in mylist:
    # do something with the item.
```

will loop over mylist from the beginning.

Comment: when I try to use the smaller list, this error comes up IndexError: index 182 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 149

Comment: Yeah, that's because you do `hectora[idx]`, when you should just do `idx`. You are also trying to subtract a list from one item in another list. I don't think that's what you want.